# How do I access a text file from within my war

Tags: java, configuration, servlets, jakarta-ee, war

How do I know what file reference to use to get a file from my WAR.

The structure of the WAR is:

> WAR
>   src
>     - model
>     - web
>    build
>     WebContent
>         META-INF
>         WEB-INF
>            LIB

The JSPs are under WebContent, I have put the config.txt file under the WebContent folder and tried to get to it with

> BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("WebContent/config.txt"));

But this doesn't work. Does anyone know what reference I need to pass or how I can figure it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). Here is [an example](http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/how-to-use-servletcontextgetresourceasstreamjavalangstring-path/18).

Answer (score 2):

I think just remove WebContent from the path while reading the file and it should help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this comes with a caveat that I'll explain below.  You should do something like this:

```
// In a Servlet
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
BufferedReader in = 
    new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sc.getRealPath("WebContent/config.txt"));
```

This assumes that your servlet container is configured to expand war files into their corresponding directory structure.

Comment: Yes I am using Tomcat and it does the expansion

Comment: @Ankur: My answer is back. I temporarily deleted it to fix a problem identified by @ChssPly76.

Answer (score -1):

The safest way to access this file should be something like this:

InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your/path/enter/here");

Comment: which works for resources in classpath, but webcontent is not.