# Where to place a file within a Java Web Project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a small java program that reads a file in, in eclipse i have the file in the main project dir and the class file is within the src dir. This works fine.

I want to you this small piece of code within a web project im working on, currently i have the class file in src/tools/, but im lost on where to put the file?

I have tried it in a few places yet it throws file not found.

Where is the best place to store this file? and how can i ensure i have the right path when using the following code?

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
```

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768270/how-do-i-access-a-text-file-from-within-my-war) for examples. I think it's the same problem you're having.

Comment: Are you using maven ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to load the file as a resource (e.g., `getResourceAsStream()`, use a path relative to the app (`getRealPath()`), or put it in an absolute location and use a full path.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction to any examples, i have been  trying this all day :( keep getting: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object

Answer (score 1):

If you put the resource file in the root of your classpath (so if your source path for java files is src/main/java then put the resource file in there) then you can do this.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myresource.txt")));
```

Now if you want you can put it in a package, so the file would be in src/main/java/com/sksamuel

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("com/sksamuel/myresource.txt")));
```

Finally, if you're using maven or something similar, then you would put the file into src/main/resources and not src/main/java, and at compile time the two paths are combined, so you would use the same code as above.

My answer assumes the file will be packaged up with your java code and is something that would change by a developer. If it's generated, or needs to be changed outside the jar/war then this isn't the best way.