# Can't locate a file in WildFly REST application

Tags: java, rest, path, jax-rs, wildfly

```
@Path("/other")
public class Testclass {
   @GET
   @Path("/filepath")
   @Produces("text/html")
   public FileInputStream login() {
       File file = new File("standalone/deployments/domaci8.war/login.html");
       try {
           return new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
       }
   }
}
```

file.getAbsolutePath() method returns this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\wildfly-10.1.0\bin\standalone\deployments\domaci8.war\login.html
```

And the login.html file is located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\wildfly-10.1.0\standalone\deployments\domaci8.war\login.html
```

Answer (score 2):

`File file = new File("standalone/deployments/domaci8.war/login.html");` is just creating a `File` object and the path to the file is relative to the folder where the JVM process is started.

Since you have started the WildFly server from  `C:\Program Files (x86)\wildfly-10.1.0\bin` using `standalone.bat` that's the reason the `file.getAbsolutePath()` is returning `C:\Program Files (x86)\wildfly-10.1.0\bin\standalone\deployments\domaci8.war\login.html`

If the `login.html` is in the same application as the rest service check https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768290/916225 this answer.

Comment: `file.getParent()` will return `null` in my problem, so the only solution I found is to create a file `new File("")` then create `String path = file.getAbsolouthPath()`, trim the string with `path = path.substring(0, path.indexOf("\\bin"))`, then you need to concatenate `path += "\\standalone\\deployments\\domaci8.war\\login.html\\"` and it works that way. Thanks for assist.

Comment: This thread finally solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845031/wildfly-getting-resource-from-war